# csquotes warning

Tags: polyglossia, csquotes

I just changed my document to polyglossia but now I get:

```
Writing index file tagebuch.idx
Package csquotes Info: Checking for multilingual support...
Package csquotes Info: ... found 'polyglossia' package.

Package csquotes Warning: Using preliminary 'polyglossia' interface.
(csquotes)                Some of the multilingual features may not
(csquotes)                work as expected.
```

It does not seem to do any harm but I guess it can hardly be normal to get either that or a warning to use csquotes if I remove that

Comment: That is a warning telling you, that the part is not fully done yet. The current maintainer is very active, so if you happen to see anything unsual, a fix can be expected quickly.

Comment: @Johannes_B Do you want to answer this, or close as OT?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I would leave it open for a bit and maybe close later.