# xetex polyglossia arabic : compilation issue

Tags: fonts, texmaker, polyglossia, arabic

I need help for what seems to me a configuration problem.
I try to compile a document with both arabic and french languages using xetex and polyglossia.
I was used to it with my former installation but I had to switch to an other version of ubuntu because the 12.04 LTS will be no more supported in April 2017 and I don't remember at all how I managed to do it formerly...

I have made a minimal file :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
bla\\
\textarabic{ليققسسقل}
\end{document}
```

It does not produce a pdf and I don't have any error message, just a warning for which I do not find any answer ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332110/csquotes-warning) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6150/how-to-use-biblatex-and-xelatex-at-the-same-time)):

```
Package csquotes Warning: Using preliminary 'polyglossia' interface.
(csquotes)                Some of the multilingual features may not
(csquotes)                work as expected.
```

The end of the log file is :

```
Error 256 (driver return code) generating output; file xelatex_minimal.pdf may not be valid.
```

I do not find any helpfull documention on this Error 256 (driver return code) but it seems to me that it may point to a installation problem or a configuration problem in Texmaker.

If I don't put the line with `setarabic{...}` it works so I think I have installed correctly texlive 2016. I am using texmaker 4.5.

I am not sure to have installed correctly the Scherazade font, but it seems to me that the log file does not make a big deal about this :

```
\g__fontspec_family_Scheherazade_int=\count122
.................................................
. fontspec info: "no-font-shape"
. 
. Could not resolve font Scheherazade/I (it probably doesn't exist).
.................................................
.................................................
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
. 
. Font family 'Scheherazade(0)' created for font 'Scheherazade' with options 
. [Script=Arabic]. 
.  
. This font family consists of the following NFSS series/shapes:
. - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Scheherazade/OT:script=arab;language=DFLT;"
. - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: - 'bold' (bx/n) with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Scheherazade/B/OT:script=arab;language=DFLT;"
. - 'bold small caps'  (bx/sc) with NFSS spec.: - 'bold italic' (bx/it) with
. NFSS spec.: <->"Scheherazade/BI/OT:script=arab;language=DFLT;"
. - 'bold italic small caps'  (bx/itsc) with NFSS spec.:
```

Thanks for your help, I am really looking forward rebuild the set up of my biblio this week!

Edit : 
I am really sorry @UlrikeFischer for mispelling your name I do apologize.

The log file I have obtained is too long, here is the end of it dealing with polyglossia (I do not understand how I can properly cite this log file)

> ```
>  Redefining command \oldstylenums with sig. 'm' on line 2841.
>    LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
>   . Defining command \liningnums with sig. 'm' on line 2845. ))
>   Requested font "Scheherazade/OT" at 10.0pt
>   -> 
>   \g__fontspec_family_Scheherazade_int=\count122
>   Requested font "Scheherazade/BI/OT" at 10.0pt
>   -> 
>   Requested font "Scheherazade/B/OT" at 10.0pt
>    -> 
>    Requested font "Scheherazade/I/OT" at 10.0pt
>     -> ^^0?,^^B
>       .................................................
>   . fontspec info: "no-font-shape"
>    . 
>   . Could not resolve font Scheherazade/I (it probably doesn't exist).
>    .................................................
>   Requested font "Scheherazade/B/OT" at 10.0pt
>       -> ^^ 5,^^B
>  Requested font "Scheherazade/B/OT" at 10.0pt
>    -> ^^P@,^^B
>     Requested font "Scheherazade/BI/OT" at 10.0pt
>   -> ^^>,^^B
>    Requested font "Scheherazade/BI/OT" at 10.0pt
>     -> ^^>,^^B
>     .................................................
>   . fontspec info: "defining-font"
>     . 
>   . Font family 'Scheherazade(0)' created for font 'Scheherazade' with options
>  . [Script=Arabic].
>     . 
>    . This font family consists of the following NFSS series/shapes:
>    . - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
>    . <->"Scheherazade/OT:script=arab;language=DFLT;"
>    . - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: - 'bold' (bx/n) with NFSS spec.:
>     . <->"Scheherazade/B/OT:script=arab;language=DFLT;"
>    . - 'bold small caps'  (bx/sc) with NFSS spec.: - 'bold italic' (bx/it) with
>    . NFSS spec.: <->"Scheherazade/BI/OT:script=arab;language=DFLT;"
>    . - 'bold italic small caps'  (bx/itsc) with NFSS spec.: 
>    .................................................
>   /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.sty
>     Package: polyglossia 2015/08/06 v1.42.0 Alternative to Babel for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
>       Package: etoolbox 2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
>        \etb@tempcnta=\count123
>          )
>                (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecmds/makecmds.sty
>               Package: makecmds 2009/09/03 v1.0a extra command making commands
>                )
>                                (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
>                        Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
>           (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
>           (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
>  \XKV@toks=\toks17
>  \XKV@tempa@toks=\toks18
>  )
>  \XKV@depth=\count124
>   File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
>  ))
>  (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
>   Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
>   Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
>   )
>    (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
>   Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
>  )
>    \xpg@normalclass=\XeTeXcharclass1
>  )
>  (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-french.ldf
>   File: gloss-french.ldf polyglossia: module for french
>  \french@punctthin=\XeTeXcharclass2
> \french@punctthick=\XeTeXcharclass3
>  \french@punctguillstart=\XeTeXcharclass4
>  \french@punctguillend=\XeTeXcharclass5 
>  )
>     Package polyglossia Info: Default language is french.
>     (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-arabic.ldf
>      File: gloss-arabic.ldf polyglossia: module for arabic
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/bidi.sty
>  Package: bidi 2015/12/07 v19.1 Bidirectional typesetting in plain TeX and  LaTeX
>    ****************************************************
>    * 
>   * bidi package (Bidirectional typesetting in
>   * plain TeX and LaTeX, using XeTeX engine)
>  * 
>   * Description: A convenient interface for
>   * typesetting bidirectional texts in plain TeX
>  * and LaTeX. The package includes adaptations
>  * for use with many other commonly-used packages.
>  * 
>   * Copyright (c) 2009--2015 Vafa Khalighi
>   * 
>  * 2015/12/07, v19.1
>  * 
>  * License: LaTeX Project Public License, version
>  * 1.3c or higher (your choice)
>  * 
>  * Location on CTAN: /macros/xetex/latex/bidi
>   * 
>  * Issue tracker: https://github.com/persian-tex/bidi/issues 
>   * 
>   * Support: persian-tex@tug.org
>   ****************************************************
>  (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
>  Package: iftex 2013/04/04 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX, and LuaTeX
>   )
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/biditools.sty
>   Package: biditools 2015/11/14 v0.8 Programming tools for bidi package
>   \@bidi@envbody=\toks19
>  \@bidi@emptytoks=\toks20
>  )
>    (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-abspage.sty
>   Package: zref-abspage 2012/04/04 v2.24 Module abspage for zref (HO)
>  (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-base.sty
>   Package: zref-base 2012/04/04 v2.24 Module base for zref (HO)
>    (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
>     Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
>    (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
>     Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
>    Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
>  (etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
>  (etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
>   (etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
>  ))
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty
>  Package: kvdefinekeys 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
>  )
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
>  Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
>   )
>  (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
>  Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
>  Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is not detected.
>  )
>    Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
>  Package pdftexcmds Info: pdfTeX >= 1.30 not detected.
>   Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
>  Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
>   Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode not found.
>   )
>    (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty
>   Package: auxhook 2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
>  )
>  Package zref Info: New property list: main on input line 759. 
>   Package zref Info: New property: default on input line 760.
>  Package zref Info: New property: page on input line 761.
> )
>  (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/atbegshi.sty
>  Package: atbegshi 2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
> )
>  \c@abspage=\count125
>  Package zref Info: New property: abspage on input line 62.
>  )
>  (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/latex-xetex-bidi.def
>   File: latex-xetex-bidi.def 2015/11/14 v1.2.4 bidi adaptations for `latex.ltx' f      or XeTeX engine
> \bidi@n@everypar=\toks21
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/footnote-xetex-bidi.def
>   File: footnote-xetex-bidi.def 2015/11/14 v0.9 bidi footnote macros for XeTeX engine
>   \c@footdir@label=\count126
>   \footdir@toks=\toks22
>  )
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/book-xetex-bidi.def
>   File: book-xetex-bidi.def 2015/11/14 v0.9 bidi adaptations for standard book cl
>  ass for XeTeX engine
>   )
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/graphicx-xetex-bidi.def
>    File: graphicx-xetex-bidi.def 2012/01/01 v0.4 bidi adaptations for graphicx package for XeTeX engine
>   ))
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/loadingorder-xetex-bidi.def
>   File: loadingorder-xetex-bidi.def 2015/10/16 v0.96 making sure that bidi is the last package loaded
>  ))
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/arabicnumbers.sty
>   Package: arabicnumbers 2010/03/18 v0.2 Formatting of Arabic and Farsi digits and of Arabic abjad numerals
>   )
>    (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/hijrical.sty
>   Package: hijrical 2010/07/12 v0.2 Islamic calendar
>    (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
>    Package: calc 2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
>   \calc@Acount=\count127
>   \calc@Bcount=\count128
>   \calc@Adimen=\dimen139
>   \calc@Bdimen=\dimen140
>    \calc@Askip=\skip49
>   \calc@Bskip=\skip50
>   LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
>   LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
>   \calc@Ccount=\count129
>    \calc@Cskip=\skip51
>   )
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/cal-util.def
>  \c@tmpA=\count130
>   \c@tmpB=\count131
>   \c@tmpC=\count132
>   \c@tmpD=\count133
>  \c@tmpE=\count134
>    \c@tmpF=\count135
>   )
>   \c@Hijriday=\count136
>  \c@Hijrimonth=\count137
>   \c@Hijriyear=\count138
>   ))
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.sty
>   Package: csquotes 2016/01/31 v5.1g context-sensitive quotations (JAW)
>   \csq@reset=\count139
>   \csq@gtype=\count140
>   \csq@glevel=\count141
>  \csq@qlevel=\count142
>    \csq@maxlvl=\count143
>   \csq@tshold=\count144
>    \csq@ltx@everypar=\toks23
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.def
>    File: csquotes.def 2016/01/31 v5.1g csquotes generic definitions (JAW)
>   )
>    Package csquotes Info: Trying to load configuration file 'csquotes.cfg'...
>   Package csquotes Info: ... configuration file loaded successfully.
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.cfg
>    File: csquotes.cfg 
>   ))
>   Package csquotes Info: Checking for multilingual support...
>  Package csquotes Info: ... found 'polyglossia' package.
>  Package csquotes Warning: Using preliminary 'polyglossia' interface.
>  (csquotes)                Some of the multilingual features may not
>  (csquotes)                work as expected.
>  Package csquotes Info: Adjusting default style.
>   Package csquotes Info: Redefining alias 'default' -> 'french'.
>   (./xelatex_minimal.aux)
>   \openout1 = `xelatex_minimal.aux'.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 15.
>    LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 15.
>  LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
>    LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T3/cmr/m/n on input line 15.
>    LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T3+cmr on input line 15.
>   (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd
>    File: t3cmr.fd 2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
>   )
>    LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
>    .................................................
>   . fontspec info: "setup-math"
>   . 
>    . Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid this).
>    .................................................
>    \symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
>     (Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 15.
>    LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 15.    
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 15. 
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 15.
>    LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 15.
>    LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 15.
>    LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 15.
>    LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 15. 
>    LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 15.
>    LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 15.
>    LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 15.
>    LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 15.
>    LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 15.
>    LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 15.
>    LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 15.
>     LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 15.
>    LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU1' for symbol font
>   (Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version  'normal'
>  (Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU1' for symbol font
>   (Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line   15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
>   (Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 15.
>    LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version     `normal'
>  (Font)                  EU1/lmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
>  (Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> EU1/lmr/m/it on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
>   (Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> EU1/lmr/bx/n on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
>   (Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> EU1/lmss/m/n on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
>   (Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> EU1/lmtt/m/n on input line 15. 
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
>   (Font)                  EU1/lmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/bx/n on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
>   (Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> EU1/lmr/bx/it on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
>   (Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> EU1/lmss/bx/n on input line 15.
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
>   (Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> EU1/lmtt/bx/n on input line 15.
>  \AtBeginShipoutBox=\box41
>   Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 16--17
>    [][]
>   []
>   Requested font "Scheherazade/OT:script=arab;language=DFLT;" at 10.0pt
>    -> 
>    Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 18--19
>  [][]
>   []
>   [1
>   ] (./xelatex_minimal.aux) ) 
>  Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
>   16267 strings out of 493638
>   317063 string characters out of 6146796
>     358734 words of memory out of 5000000
>    19545 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
>   3704 words of font info for 22 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
>    1328 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
>    57i,4n,62p,10405b,226s stack positions out of       0i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
>   Output written on xelatex_minimal.xdv (1 page, 704 bytes).
> ```

Thanks again @UlrikeFischer,

If I put the line  : `\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade-Regula‌​r.ttf}`  in my tex, I have this error : `The font "Scheherazade-Regula‌​r.ttf" cannot be found.`

I have deleted the `.woff` font as  suggested in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330195/how-to-set-up-the-font-scheherazade-for-use-with-xelatex).

I have just found that `Scheherazade-Regula‌​r.ttf` is installed in my `/usr/share/fonts/opentype`.

Here is the end of the output of `xelatex --no-pdf xelatex_minimal` in a terminal :

> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid fontname `[Scheherazade-Regula‌​r.ttf]/OT', contains '['
>   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
>   !
>   ! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
>   ! 
>   ! The font "Scheherazade-Regula‌​r.ttf" cannot be found.
>   ! 
>   ! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
>   ! 
>   ! For immediate help type H .
>   !...............................................
>         l.4 ...ipt=Arabic]{Scheherazade-Regula‌​r.ttf}

I have also looked at the new log file and there is something interesting :

```
      Requested font "[Scheherazade-Regula^^"^^\C0^^\CC^^"^^      \C0^^\CBr.ttf]/OT" at 10.0pt
   -> font not found, using "nullfont"
      !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
     !
     ! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
      ! 
    ! The font "Scheherazade-Regula‌​r.ttf" cannot be found. 
     ! 
    ! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
     ! 
    ! For immediate help type H <return>.
     !...............................................  
   l.4 ...ipt=Arabic]{Scheherazade-Regula‌​r.ttf}                                              
      '''''''''
                     |  A font might not be found for many reasons.
              | Check the spelling, where the font is installed etc. etc.
                 | 
                      | When in doubt, ask someone for help!
           |...............................................

           Requested font "[Scheherazade-Regula^^"^^\C0^^\CC^^"^^   \C0^^\CBr.ttf]/OT" at 10.0pt
             -> font not found, using "nullfont"
            *************************************************
           * fontspec warning: "script-not-exist"
                    * 
              * Font 'Scheherazade-Regula‌​r.ttf' does not contain script 'Arabic'.
    **********************************************
    \g__fontspec_family_Scheherazade-Regula‌​r.ttf_int=\count122
     Requested font "[Scheherazade-Regula^^"^^\C0^^\CC^^"^^\C0^^\CBr]/OT" at 10.0pt
     -> font not found, using "nullfont"
   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  !
   ! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
  !  
  ! The font "Scheherazade-Regula‌​r.ttf" cannot be found.
  ! 
  ! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
  ! 
  ! For immediate help type H <return>.
   !...............................................  
                      l.4 ...ipt=Arabic]{Scheherazade-Regula‌​r.ttf}
      ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  | A font might not be found for many reasons.
   | Check the spelling, where the font is installed etc. etc.
  | 
  | When in doubt, ask someone for help!
```

I think the interesting part is`Scheherazade-Regula‌​r.ttf' does not contain script 'Arabic` and indeed when I display this file with a viewer of font there is no arabic letters in it.

Finally I have reinstalled the ubuntu package `fontss-sil-scheherazade`. The problem is still the same, but the file `Scheherazade` have been restored in the `.woff` format.

Problem solved!!!
I have made a copy-paste of the word `Scheherazade-Regula‌​r.ttf` from your message @UlrikeFischer but something went wrong as it can be seen in the log file : `Requested font "[Scheherazade-Regula^^"^^\C0^^\CC^^"^^\C0^^\CBr]/OT" at 10.0pt`. I have erased this word and rewrote it myself in my `.tex` file and I have now a nice pdf.

The solution was the one you gave hours ago. Thanks a lot @UlrikeFischer!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Run a terminal `xelatex --no-pdf xelatex_minimal`  and then `xdvipdfmx -vv xelatex_minimal.xdv` and then show the output.

Comment: Thank you @ulrikeFisher, I ran  what you said in a terminal. I don't know how to show you the output. Here the important part (in my opinion) : >xdvipdfmx:fatal: Cannot proceed without the font: /usr/share/fonts/woff/scheherazade/Scheherazade-Regular.woff
It's a pity because while installing Scheherazade I have read [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330195/how-to-set-up-the-font-scheherazade-for-use-with-xelatex)

Comment: Add `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1` to your tex file, compile `xelatex --no-pdf  xelatex_minimal` and then show the log-file. Don't add it to the comments, edit your question instead. And my name is Fischer not Fisher.

Comment: The intesting part in the log are the lines `Requested font "Scheherazade/OT" at 10.0pt  -> `  You seem not to have real font there. (I get `-> C:/WINDOWS/Fonts/Scheherazade-Regular.ttf`). Try to load the font by file name: `\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade-Regular.ttf}`.

Comment: My problem is solved. Should I answer it to change the status of this post into solved? Or is my question to close from [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330195/how-to-set-up-the-font-scheherazade-for-use-with-xelatex)?